# Where's my value?

Tags: code-golf, array

My [boss](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137209/efficient-robot-movement) now wants me to implement a mechanism that lets him search for an item in an array, and gives him the index/indices where that value occurs.

### Your Task:

Write a program or function that receives an array and a value (String, Integer, Float, or Boolean), and returns the indices of the array at which the value occurs (either 0 or 1 indexed, whichever you prefer).  If the value is not in the array return an empty array.

### Input:

An array A and a value V, that may or may not be present in A.

### Output:

An array containing the indice(s) at which the V occurs in A, or, if V does not occur in A, an empty array.

### Test Cases:

Please note that the test cases are 0 based.

```
12, [12,14,14,2,"Hello World!",3,12,12]         -> [0,6,7]
"Hello World", ["Hi", "Hi World!", 12,2,3,True] -> []
"a", ["A",True,False,"aa","a"]                  -> [4]
12, [12,"12",12]                                -> [0,2]
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest score in bytes wins.

Comment: Can we assume that the given array only has *one* of those types (i.e. no arrays with mixed types) as many languages do not support arrays or lists with more than one type.

Comment: Sure, @flawr.  You may assume that the array will only consist of values of the same type as the value to check for, if your language requires it.

Comment: Are the comparisons supposed to be done without any type coercion? (e.g. "12" != 12)

Comment: That's correct, @Arnauld.  "12"!=12.  You should only return an index if your value exactly matches the value at that index.

Comment: All your arrays are 1D. Assumption?

Comment: @Adám I think that's indeed a valid assumption, since an inner array/list isn't part of (quote) "_and a value (String, Integer, Float, or Boolean)_".

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I meant the array to be searched. It could be multi-D.

Comment: @Adám Ah oops, misread. But I think it's still a valid assumption.

Comment: Can I use a language that only support integers?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, sorry, but no.  You must support at least strings, integers, floats and booleans.

Comment: @Adám, valid assumption.  All arrays you must handle will be 1D (kudos to you if you support more though).

Comment: Must integers+floats+booleans all be separate? (integers + floats are the same in JS, integers + booleans are the same in a lot of languages)

Comment: No, you simply need to support some sort of numerical value that allows for decimal values, strings, and booleans of some sort.

Comment: Okay, so `1` and `True` don't have to be two different things. But can we use a language that only supports numbers (representing strings as lists of integers)?

Comment: @Zacharý - As long as it can take ["A"],"A" in some form and return [0], it's good. If it represents strings as lists of integers, then it should check if the lists of integers that represent strings are equal.

Comment: Okay. And I'm surprised there hasn't been a language yet that can do it in 1 byte!

Comment: Is output printed on standard out allowed, or just by function return?

Comment: @Jakob, standard output is allowed.

Comment: Can the value _V_ be null?

Comment: No, although if your code supports null for V, that's great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io), 2 bytes

0-indexed.

```
xE
```

**[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xE&input=%22a%22%0A%5B%22A%22%2CTrue%2CFalse%2C%22aa%22%2C%22a%22%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B12%2C14%2C14%2C2%2C%22Hello+World%21%22%2C3%2C12%2C12%5D%0A12&debug=0&input_size=2)** or **[Check all the Test Cases](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xE&input=%22a%22%0A%5B%22A%22%2CTrue%2CFalse%2C%22aa%22%2C%22a%22%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B12%2C14%2C14%2C2%2C%22Hello+World%21%22%2C3%2C12%2C12%5D%0A12%0A%0A%5B%22Hi%22%2C+%22Hi+World%21%22%2C+12%2C2%2C3%2CTrue%5D%0A%22Hello+World%22%0A%0A%5B%22A%22%2CTrue%2CFalse%2C%22aa%22%2C%22a%22%5D%0A%22a%22%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

---

## Explanation

```
xEQ  - Full Program. Takes Input from standard input. Q means evaluated input and is implicit at the end of the program.

x   - Get all the indexes of x in y
 E  - Evaluated Input #2 - The value
  Q - The list - Evaluated Input #1
```

Comment: You're supposed to return all occurrences not just the first.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Fixed. Just take them in reverse order.

Comment: Pyth is definitely the best tool for the job then :P

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

*-3  bytes thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer and @Chris_Rands*

```python
lambda y,x:[i for i,j in enumerate(x)if j==y]
```

**[Test Suite.](https://tio.run/##VYtBCoMwEEX3PcU0qwRmY@yqkEU3xQMIXVgXKSY0EhNJFfT06Si0tDD8gf/@G9fpGUOZrbpnr4dHp2HF5dw4sDGBwx5cABPmwSQ9Gb4IZ6FXam3zmFyYuOWFRGgoitN2ElllvI9wi8l3R4Ylbky2Qhw@xu@CkcwqR4/yKwE5ktQ6zebP1Pv@wnaCV@1fBpmmlkgLIER@Aw)**

Today I learned `enumerate(x) == zip(range(len(x)),x)`.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda n,l:[x for x in range(len(l))if l[x]==n]
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcmxCoAgEIDhV7maFG7JmgL33qDBHIy0hOsMabCnt4Kfb/mv5z4S9zXopZI7180BI42mQEgZCkSG7Hj3gjwLkjIGIFOs1mzrlSPfIohOIZiPbvhT2E6eKMGcMm1Niz3@T1kp6ws)** or **[Check all the Test Cases](https://tio.run/##VYtBCsIwEEX3nmLMKoHZNHUldOFGeoCCi5pFpIkGxqTECvX0cVpQFIY/8N9/42u6pVgX35wL2ftlsBCR9v0MPmWYIUTINl6dJBclKRU8UD@bpommjDnESXpZaYSeo9otp1G0jijBKWUatgJrXJg2Sm0@xu9CsCzawI/zKwE7mtUuP92fadf9QawEj5YeDoXllokBUKq8AQ)**

Comment: Use `enumerate()` to bring it down a couple of bytes

Comment: @Chris_Rands Ended up being longer.

Comment: `lambda n,l:[x for x,y in enumerate(l)if y==n]`

Comment: I meant what @EriktheOutgolfer said

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fixed.

Comment: Once again, Python golfed code that's essentially idiomatic non-golfed solution :)

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Yeah, sort of...

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript, 39 bytes

```js
e=>a=>[...a.keys()].filter(i=>a[i]===e)
```

```js
f=
e=>a=>[...a.keys()].filter(i=>a[i]===e)

console.log(f(12)([12,14,14,2,"Hello World!",3,12,12]));
console.log(f("Hello World")(["Hi", "Hi World!", 12,2,3,true]));
console.log(f("a")(["A",true,false,"aa","a"])); 
console.log(f(12)([12,14,14,2,"Hello World!",3,12,'12']));
```

The above snippet might not work on all browsers, so here's a [TIO link](https://tio.run/##FcnBCsIwDADQX9GdUqiBVm@Snf0DD6WHsqVSDYu0Q9jXdw7e7b3TL7Wplu96WXTmnqkzjYnGgIgJP7w1MBFzkZUrlH@FEomITZ90aSqMoi/I4LyB4Lx1t4O3w4NF9PTUKvN5sFd7nI/G3PsO).

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
mf
```

The `m` consumes two arguments, and checks each element in the array whether is equal to the other argument, `f` returns the indices of the truthy entries of an array.

[Try it online!](https://matl.suever.net/?code=mf&inputs=%7B%27Hi%27%2C+%27Hi+World%21%27%2C+12%2C+2%2C+3%2C+%27Hi+World%21%27%7D%0A%27Hi+World%21%27&version=20.2.2)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for the proposed test cases, same for the Octave solution.

Comment: You should use `ismember` instead of `=` to properly handle arrays of strings. [`mf`](https://matl.suever.net/?code=mf&inputs=%7B%27Hi%27%2C+%27Hi+World%21%27%2C+12%2C+2%2C+3%7D%0A%27Hi+World%21%27&version=20.2.2)

Comment: @LuisMendo We don't need to consider mixed input, see clarification from OP!

Comment: @flawr Oh, _why_ is that only in a comment, and not in the challenge text? :-/

Comment: You'd have to ask the OP, not me:)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>44</s> 43 bytes

<sup>*Crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(*</sup>

```
v=>a=>a.map((x,i)=>x===v&&++i).filter(x=>x)
```

*Saved 1 bytes thanks to* [@Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)

```js
let f=
v=>a=>a.map((x,i)=>x===v&&++i).filter(x=>x)
;

console.log(f(12)([12,14,14,2,"Hello World!",3,12,12]));         // => [1,7,8]
console.log(f("Hello World")(["Hi", "Hi World!", 12,2,3,true])); // => []
console.log(f("a")(["A",true,false,"aa","a"]));                  // => [5]
```

Comment: Can you make the `===` a normal `==` for one byte less?  I came up with literally the same thing, variable names and all haha.

Comment: `===` is necessary to distinguish `12` from `"12"`

Comment: @kamoroso94 no, [here](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/)'s why.

Answer (score 6):

## R (+pryr), 20 bytes

```
pryr::f(which(a==b))
```

Which evaluates to the function

```
function (a, b) 
which(a == b)
```

Where either `a` can be the value to look for and `b` the vector, or the other way around. When presented with two vectors of unequal lengths (a single value counts as a length-1 vector in R), R will wrap the shorter one to match the length of the longer one. Then the equality is checked. This generates a logical vector. `which` provides the indices where this vector is true.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYu7CsMwDEX3fIWqyQItcbt6yJCSIVMfdHbdmhhMDCGhn@9KLZSCuOI@zlKjq3Gbw5rKDMYz3Ama15TCZDw4J7ZG01qGoNoe9Czj8My5wK0s@bFD3rN2lgigiea/RAVxSPJFfwDI3gp2OV17ImX8d9nhJ@NjN557Ri@xVET1DQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
⁼€T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R455HTWtC/v//H21opKNgaALBQKaSB1BFvkJ4flFOiqKSjoIxUAakwij2v6ERAA)

-1 thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder). (dyadic chains)

Comment: Nice one. I am surprised Jelly does not have a pure built-in, like Pyth does.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I think most don't.

Comment: The irony of dyadic chains :)

Answer (score 5):

## C#, <s>88</s> 72 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;a=>o=>a.Select((i,n)=>o.Equals(i)?n:-1).Where(n=>n>=0)
```

*Saved 16 bytes thanks to @LiefdeWen.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBNT8MwDIbv/RUmp0TqIlo4sbUITeNLIKHtsAPikHUeBKUOa1IQmvbbS9oKNgQ3sJTEid/keZ3CDUpLtiFVontRBcLs3Xks5Y2mdbSJIERhlHNw1@X9SRvOK68LeLV6CbdKExdfpZ2ojfOaipFdPGPh7x/i/W0MY2tMSLQlJy@QsNKFvJpQXWKlFgZHmnye57CCrFFZbrNcyRm2NzjXMYlwJCfrWhnHtTilk0Ei5PwJK@SU5ZRnh6IZRt/MjAPJGpTzSnsMPSJ3vtL0KK9taIEBi2HFCd/g0/AGkjSG5LgfIWWXaIyFua3M8iDIj@JekW4FT1IhxPBvQNgEhGYtSO8oLSLtYL6qEQJr3wf7H@wZ658PtfClYWFKtUYU64DqJ@ZX5hTVskPuibdRP2@bDw)

Comment: Amazing, I was still trying to figure out why `i==o` doesn't work.

Comment: @LiefdeWen Boxed value types.

Comment: 72 bytes `using System.Linq;a=>b=>a.Select((x,i)=>x.Equals(b)?i:-1).Where(x=>x>=0)`

Comment: @LiefdeWen Nice one, I wouldn't have thought of switching it around.

Comment: You can save a lot :) : https://tio.run/##rZBNSwMxEIbv@yvGnBJYA129tbsgpX6hIPbQQymSbqc6kk1sklWk9Lev2V20Fb3pQDKTzJs8b1L648oa2xhVoX9RJcL03Qes5A2ZTbJNIEaplfdw19X9Ths@qEAlvFpawa0iw8VXay9q47w25cgun7EM80V6uExhbLWOBVnj5QUadFTKq4mpK3RqqXFEJhRFAWvIG5UXNi@UnGJ7gvOHlERekJCzJ3TIKbblZFMr7bma00KIZph88zGOEKtRzhwFjM9D7oMj8yivbXTPgKWw5gbf4NPrFgZZCoPTfsSSXaLWFmbW6dVRlJ@kvSLbCT7IhBDDvwFhGxHEWhDtKS0i62DB1QiRdeiD/Q/2jPXXx178wZiYUq0RxTqg@on5lXmPatUhD8S7pJ93zQc

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
QāsÏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/8Ehj8eH@//@jDY10FAxNIBjIVPJIzcnJVwjPL8pJUVTSUTAGyoBUGMVyGRoBAA)

1-indexed.

Comment: I think both of ours mess up on inputs of: `12` and `[12,'12']`, unless he said it's chill for languages that don't really concrete type to not care about types.

Comment: I actually think that `12` ≠ `'12'` in 05AB1E because sometimes they behave differently...not sure if there's any equality test which can support such a thing though.

Comment: If we wanted to test them for integer validity our answers would be like 60-bytes using `is_alpha (a)` and `is_number (d)`, but I guess we can assume ours are valid until told otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>46 40</s> 39 bytes

```rb
->e,a{i=-1;a.map{|x|i+=1;x==e&&i}-[!1]}
```

Saved 7 bytes!!! thanks to Eric Duminil.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5VJ7E601bX0DpRLzexoLqmoiZT29bQusLWNlVNLbNWN1pRsSC29n@BQlq0oZGOAogwNAEhIx0lj9ScnHyF8PyinBRFJR1jHZCcUWzsfwA)

Comment: -1 byte with `!1` for `false`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```hs
v!l=fst<$>(filter((==v).snd)$zip[1..]l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7BaoQwEAbgc32K3@AhARHW9tgUKlTq2dIeFg8DyW5DU7ONqYfiu9uoFcpeZmDmn495p@FDWzvPY2rlaQj32QM/GRu051zKURRDr0T2Yy7HQ1F0VsyKAuFVtmiDN/15atD0YapRW0dhqlA5Z6G0N2Pc8qcvkXyS6SGhXHJziScBGXiDQynS49LyWO72UuZowZ7jRw5vzlvFcjS4zfdg2f1DrpLRWyaGbYbZxukqxGus@oKhwov/1lcU/QGPbA8svSY76BUk2mBiXQLMvw)

*Saved two bytes thanks to @flawr*

Haskell is statically typed, so I had to use a little workaround to run the test cases.

Comment: You don't need your workaround anymore, see the comment of the OP.

Comment: Also define a operator `v#l=...` instead of `f v l=...`, will save you two bytes:)

Comment: @flawr I had the idea of `v!l=...`, but didn't kow if it was accepted. I'll edit the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Using `map` on some `filter` expression is often an indicator that a list comprehension might be shorter: `v!l=[i|(i,x)<-zip[1..]l,x==v]`.

Comment: There is also a builtin, but unfortunately it is [longer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137371/24877) than Laikionis suggestion:)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
`fNm=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyHNL9f2////xv@jTXWMdYyA2FjHMBYA) 1-indexed.

#### Explanation

```
       -- implicitly input a value v and a list L
   m=  -- map "equals v" over the list L, resulting in a list of truthy and falsy values
`fN    -- filter the natural numbers N by discarding the numbers at falsy positions 
          and keeping the ones at truthy positions
```

Comment: Does this work for arrays with strings, though?

Comment: @officialaimm It works for lists containing only strings: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyHNL9f2////SolJyUr/o5VMlXTATCCJYIHJisoqpVgA "Husk – Try It Online") Lists of mixed types are not supported by Haskell and thus by Husk, but OP allowed this explicitly in the comments.

Comment: Is there a documentation of Husk?

Comment: @flawr Yes, it's in the wiki on the github page: https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki

Comment: @flawr If you have questions about the docs of Husk in general, join us in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53097/husk)!

Comment: should just be `¥ ` now.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Takes item to look for as left argument (must be scalar to find an *item* of the lookup array rather than a subarray) and the lookup array (which may have up to 15 dimensions) as right argument. Returns list of indices, each of which may has as many elements as the number of dimensions in the lookup array.

```apl
⍸⍷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGCo965yqk5RcpGOgmJRanpiiUpBaXFP/PzANKPurd8ah3@///hkYKmXkKQC1ewf5@CurRhkY6hiYgZKSj5JGak5OvEJ5flJOiqKRjrAOSM4pV59J41NWkjiSprolqhpJHppKOApCE61UAajUCmlBSVJoKNUBHPRFDn6MSWIVOWmJOcaqOUmKiEpBQAmrA4kolQyMlsHMA)

`⍸` **ɩ**ndices where

`⍷` found

Comment: I was about to say it ties Pyth, but you know... Unicode. Wouldn't this be 2 bytes in APL Dyalog Classic (since it uses SBCS)?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder `⍸` isn't in the character set. Still, since Dyalog uses way less than 256 unique chars, it *could have* been a single byte. When we add new glyphs, we refrain from changing the character set so that backwards compatibility is maintained.

Comment: Ah, Thanks! (I have no idea how APL / Dyalog works)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder APL is a commercial language (not a golfing language), so Dyalog have certain obligations to existing subscribers.

Comment: APL isn't a golfing language, but there do exist open-source APL implementations (ngn and GNU).

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 38 bytes

```
->e,a{a.each_index.select{|x|a[x]==e}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165YJ7E6US81MTkjPjMvJbVCrzg1JzW5pLqmoiYxuiLW1ra4tvZ/gUJatKGRjgKIMDQBISMdJY/UnJx8hfD8opwURSUdYx2QnFFs7H8A)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 101 bytes

```
=IfError(Join(",",Filter(Column(Offset(A1,0,0,1,Counta(Split(B1,",")))),Exact(Split(B1,","),A1))),"")
```

Value `V` in `A1` and array `A` in `B1` with each entry separated by a comma. Null entires are not allowed (row 5 below shows what happens).

[image: Result]

Explanation:

`Offset(A1,0,0,1,Counta(Split(B1,",")))` returns a range that is one row tall and as many columns wide as there are entries in `A1`.

`=IfError(Join(",",Filter(Column(~),Exact(Split(B1,","),A1))),"")` filters the column numbers of that range based on whether or not the value in `A1` is exactly each of the values in `B1` and concatenates them all in a comma-delineated list.

Answer (score 3):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 40 bytes

First attempt at code golf.

`keep-indexed` maps a function over a collection here, passing the current index into the callback and yielding any non-nil return values.

```clj
(fn[a b](keep-indexed #(if(= %2 a)%1)b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvBCoMwEAV/5VURdiEesu219/5BDyEHbVZIuyQSLPTvrcLAHIZ5WX1/m@5kuiEcXkqYMEf6qK5jLkl/mtBTXuiOQTDx4Hlm3iNobblsVkAKLwhenL@diOsealbxrM3SpXNXdzaJfHx/)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 86 bytes

```
@set i=0
:g
@if "%~2"=="" exit/b
@if %1==%2 echo %i%
@set/ai+=1
@shift/2
@goto g
```

Takes input as command line parameters (value then the array elements as separate parameters). Note: String quoting is considered part of the match e.g. `"1"` won't equal `1` (would cost 6 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda l,v:filter(lambda i:l[i]==v,range(len(l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFHp8wqLTOnJLVIAyqSaZUTnRlra1umU5SYl56qkZOap5Gjqan5v6AoM69EIU0j2lBHwUhHwVhHwRCMjGKBlOZ/AA)

Not short enough, but I thought it was cool. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 28 bytes

```perl
sub{grep$_[$_]eq$_[0],1..@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxRC4IwFIXf/RW3JViwJC0pkKJewh8Q9BAiE@8qWMw29yDRb1/TIEo4nAvn3PPVqERifQ4bsNqUz4vC2i/OfpHjw915TqMw3BUvm3pGI3BkjVEIgWZtkHrOgUsFPp9tJ1FMOy07xZRkKISEk1SiGhG66Lt4msIY9FUaUUGJEMEK1v@U3x2hQLLbx78kcKDY8Y7K4ACH97ppBzjWzfekf6cHJjRSwlzoisE6sW8)

The output is 1-indexed.
An anonymous function is quite unusual for Perl, but it happens to be the shortest I could think of. `grep ..., 1 .. @_` iterates over the indexes of the input array (actually it goes one cell beyond the last, but it doesn't matter), keeping only the index that satisfy `$_[$_]eq$_[0]`, ie. the ones where the value of the element (`$_[$_]`) is the same as the value we need to keep (`$_[0]`).

---

Slightly longer (31 bytes (30 + `-l` flag)), but as a full program:

```perl
$@=<>;$@eq$_&&print$.-1while<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdHP@qzjY2thZqzikFqrEq6kVFGXmlajo6RqWZ2TmpNrY/f9vaMQFQiYgZMSl5JGak5OvEJ5flJOiqMRlzAWRBgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>37</s> 33 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
findIndices.(==)
```

Thanks @Laikoni for -4 bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrzTYtMy/FMy8lMzm1WE/D1lbzf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqCkUK0kY6xjpGOCRCb6hjFcnH@BwA)

Comment: Pointfree is shorter: `findIndices.(==)`

Comment: Oh right, that is even more pointfree, thanks=)

Comment: Why not `elemIndices`?

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>146</s> <s>113</s> <s>112</s> <s>111</s> <s>110</s> 108 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;l->o->{List r=new Stack();for(int i;(i=l.indexOf(o))>-1;l.set(i,null))r.add(i);return r;}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@TAsk* by using `Vector` instead of `ArrayList`.
-1 byte by using `Stack` instead of `Vector`.
-2 bytes thanks to *@Jakob* by inputting a `ArrayList` instead of an array.

0-indexed

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##xVA9T8MwFNz7Kx6ebJS4SmFzG6kLYgAVqQMDYnATB5y6dmS/FKKqvz04UKBSGSsh@eN0d/K7cy23MnWNsnW57vWmcR6hjhxvURt@KQBgPIYHGWlXAb4qWHWo0sK1Fkcn/qq1BWpn@c0BiFFhZAhwL7XdjQACStQFfMvTufeyu9MBp4tVrQrMk1/ti0ngWM5zKGAGvUlzl@a7QQI/s@oNliiLNWWicp5qi6AF1TPDtS3V@6KijrE8zYThQSHViW2NYcxzWZZUM@EVtt6CF/texJRxNe3KxKCHvFunS9jEDnSJXtuXp2eQbOgDyy6g2nDXIm@igsbSgsumMR0dUp30o59M4DIMLM0mCWTXXztCcquMcfDovCkvSAJXURkcE8bY4dUBi3@Z/GMxJTlPBjKPk9C3KoFKmhAvIiUZTnI0VpLzNSbZhPz9n/vRvv8A)

```java
import java.util.*;    // Required import for Vector and Vector
l->o->{                // Method with List and Object parameters
  List r=new Stack();  //  Result-list
  for(int i;(i=l.indexOf(o))>=-1;
                       //  Loop as long as we can find the object in the list
    l.set(i,null))     //   After every iteration, remove the found item from the list
      r.add(i);        //    Add the index to the result-list
                       //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;            //  Return the result-List
}                      // End of method
```

Comment: Cool! If I am not wrong `Vector` may save few bytes. :)

Comment: @TAsk Thanks! Need to remember that one. I use `List`+`ArrayList` pretty often.

Comment: `List r=new Vector();` will work, too.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by taking a list instead: [TIO](https://tio.run/##fVGxasMwEJ3trzgyScUWpNAOdWLoEii0ZMhYOii2HOQokpHOaULwt7tSopK0Q0Ac4r13uqd3Ld/z3HRCt/V2lLvOWITWY6xHqdhDkaZdv1aygkpx5@CDSw2nNOms3HMU4JCjJ68dTa8rlEazRbzMrtyrtfz4Lh3OlutWVFhmdxsvolvNbW9Zwkbgm67FYSF9tTAfVV6avDwFGdi5Ft@wQl5tCS0aY4nUCLIgcq5YaDgsG2IoLfNpoZgTSGSme6UotYzXNZG0sAJ7q8EWw5j4IJKYRPzz3sgadj4PskIr9ebzC7jdOBriSfw8IBenHveZvUCw84t4LKiS0zSDxwwmjTGTITsj57uH1txOIpNBMBb5Z/aUQcOVExEYfB0uU5PV0aHYMdMj8xvSqDT5GxLjXaeOJHi5sxfyj3OMu8D7CCml8Y2zNUqLMD71Zxh/AA). Seems like a small enough change not to merit a separate answer.

Comment: The change breaks searching for `null`, but that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
Qƶ0K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/8Ng2A@///6MNdYx0jHVMdEyB2BjIhvNjuYwB)

**It is 1-indexed, as shown below:**

```
IN A-#------------------------> [2,3,3,3,4]
IN B-#------------------------> 3
-----#------------------------+-----------------
Q    # Vectorized equivalence | [0,1,1,1,0]
 ƶ   # Lift by index          | [0,2,3,4,0]
  0K # Remove zeros           | [2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 12 bytes

```
Position@##&
```

1-Indexed

**input** [Array,Value]

> [{12, 14, 14, 2, "Hello World!", 3, 12, 12}, 12]

**output**

> {{1}, {7}, {8}}

Comment: Why not just `Position`?

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 29 bytes

```
e#l=[i|(i,h)<-zip[0..]l,h==e]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1U5xzY6s0YjUydD00a3KrMg2kBPLzZHJ8PWNjX2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKgqGRgrJCtIGOoY6hkY6xjgmIMtMxB1GWsf8B)

Comment: Does that work with the heterogeneous input cases? (Mixtures of integers, strings, a "true" value, etc).

Comment: @Kaz: no, it doesn't. It's polymorphic and works for every type where equality is defined for, but all list elements have to be of the same type. According to a comment in the OP that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
mÈ¶V©YÄÃf
```

1-indexed.

Japt input doesn't support booleans, so they have been replaced with `0` and `1` in the test cases.

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=bci2VqlZxMNm&inputs=WzEyLDE0LDE0LDIsIkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISIsMywxMiwxMl0KMTI=,WyJIaSIsIkhpIFdvcmxkISIsMTIsMiwzLHRydWVdCiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCI=,WyJBIiwgMSwgMCwgImFhIiwgImEiXQoiYSI=,WzEyLCIxMiIsMTJdCjEy&flags=LVE=) with the `-Q` flag to format the array output.

### 0-indexed Solution, 11 bytes

```
l o f@gX ¶V
```

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=bCBvIGZAZ1ggtlY=&inputs=WzEyLDE0LDE0LDIsIkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISIsMywxMiwxMl0KMTI=,WyJIaSIsIkhpIFdvcmxkISIsMTIsMiwzLHRydWVdCiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCI=,WyJBIiwgMSwgMCwgImFhIiwgImEiXQoiYSI=,WzEyLCIxMiIsMTJdCjEy&flags=LVE=)

Comment: One of the few times `¶` rather than `¥` comes in handy :P I was thinking of doing something along the lines of `m@Y*(X¶V} f`, but I hadn't realized that wouldn't work for index `0`. 1-indexing is clever...

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 21 bytes

```
{grep :k,*===$^v,@^z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Or0otUDBKltHy9bWViWuTMchrqr2v7VCcWKlQpqGoZGOAphQMjRS0lEwNNLUtP4PAA)

The `:k` adverb to `grep` tells it to return the matching keys (indices) of the input sequence that match the predicate `* === $^v`.

If strings and numbers were considered equivalent, one could use a grep predicate of just `$^v` instead of `* === $^v`.

Comment: `eqv` might be better than `===` depending on what you want to consider equivalent values.

Answer (score 1):

### C <s>340</s> <s>362</s> <s>166</s> 115 Bytes

Hello all. My first time here. I figured since I enjoy (attempting) to write optimized code I may as well give this a try.

@Rodney - ~39 bytes from the includes

@Zacharý - 7 bytes with implicit typing

**0-indexed**.

**How to Run:**

As per @Arnolds suggestion, the program takes arguments in a much more C friendly manner. This let me reduce the size of the file by a little more than half.

The arguments should be passed in the following order `value [element1 ...]`
where braces indicate optional arguments

You may or may not have to add escaped quotes to any strings that are provided in order to satisfy the condition of `12 != "12"`. On my system the this can be done in the following manner

```
prog-name.exe 12 3 "Hello" 12 4 "12"
Returns [2,4]     < This is incorrect

prog-name.exe 12 3 "\"Hello\"" 12 4 "\"12\""
Returns [2]       < Correct
```

---

golfed

```
#define P printf(
b=0;main(int c,char**v){P"[");for(--c;c-1;c--)b|=strcmp(v[1],v[c])?0:P b?",%i":"%i",c-2);P"]");}
```

ungolfed

```
#define P printf(

//Implicit only works in global(I totally knew this after almost 4 years of C :P)
b = 0;
main(int c,char**v)
{

    P"[");

    //match loop
    //b is used to determine if this is the first iteration. it can be assumed that printf will always return >0
    //subract two from c to get correct index number of match
    for(--c; c-1; c--)
        b |= strcmp(v[1], v[c]) ? 0 : P b ? ",%i" : "%i", c-2);

    P"]");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I notice you have a lot of extra whitespace.  Particularly around operators `i = 0`.  These can be removed.  I suggest playing around with the whitespace a bit.

Comment: With the way you handle the list, a first argument of `,12` and second argument of `[12,14,14,2,"Hello World!",3,12,12]` prints `[5,6]` which is technically incorrect.

Comment: @ArnoldPalmer I updated the code to make it a little more verbose at detecting data types. However, since C doesn't have all the fancy type conversion such as JavaScript, it is still vulnerable to having a comma in a 'number' type. I pretty much just left it assuming correctly formatted input.

Comment: @Marcos There's a chance you may be able to take each value of the array as it's own command line argument. I don't golf in C ever, so not quite sure what the rules are, but it doesn't seem unreasonable to me that you'd be allowed to do that. Especially since accepting the array as a list leaves you vulnerable to this problem. Also, you still have a bit of white space in your golfed code. You don't need the spaces on the `#include` statements, `strstr(h+i,n)-h ==i` has an extra space, and you can do `return-1` instead of `return -1`.

Comment: are implicit declarations allowed? I think you can ditch the `#include` statements

Comment: You could change the macro to `#define P printf(`, then change the code at the bottom to `int main(int c,char**v){int b=0,i=0;P"[");for(;i<c-2;i++)b|=strcmp(v[1],v[i+2])?0:P b?",%i":"%i",i);P"]");}` to save a byte. And `int` and `#include` can be implicit in C.

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 66 bytes

```
(lambda(x s)(loop as i in s as j from 0 when(equal i x)collect j))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/RagIxEHyuXzEulO6CQi/1udA3/8CHUiG9O2lk76KXE4XS/LpuTloaNmwmM5PN1BrS4coa4wG7OIAvSILQ44m5cii7WpVyoHWrGrGJgzZzwgsK50T4P0EwGMjE4U9pOmfyUWT2YIvJF9UbYUQfFOQN250IfkdS5Wh6uzjQRLD9rfOjOSinBd7zd055u8g/H1i@TtDfYX4kWASwZfLdZ@OnQPd8PiGUaKmc9tgNscMzzl9tz@3x5NXYi9RRta1H7EWuxWrtBg)

Answer (score 1):

### [TXR Lisp](http://nongnu.org/txr), 26 bytes

```
(op where(op equal @@1)@2)
```

In other words, "Where is argument 2 equal to argument 1?"

Run:

```
1> (op where(op equal @@1) @2)
#<interpreted fun: lambda (#:arg-01-0166 #:arg-02-0167 . #:rest-0165)>
2> [*1 12 #(12 14 14 2 "Hello world!" 3 12 12)]
(0 6 7)
3> [*1 "Hello World" #("Hi" "Hi world!" 12 2 3 t)]
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
#(filter(comp #{%2}%)(range(count %)))
```

A bit obscure :) The first input argument is a `vec` of values and the second one is the searched value. `%` maps indexes to values, and the set `#{%2}` returns truthy (the input argument `%2`) or falsy `nil` for that value. [comp](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp) composes these together.

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src/ab6e6cfb6bf7?at=master), 5 bytes

```
⎕⎕=⍸↵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//9R31Qgsn3Uu@NR29b//6MNdYx0jHVMdEzBEMyL5TL9DwA)

### How?

- `⎕` evaluated line of input
- `⎕` evaluated line of input
- `=` element-wise equality
- `⍸` indexes of truthy elements
- `↵` output with new line

MY is capable of something again! Order of the inputs does not matter. Indexing is 1-based by default.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
I.@:=
```

Assumes inputs are of the same type.

I do not know J very well. This took *way* too long.

`=` is (vectorized) equality. `I.` returns the indices of 1s in an array. `@:` is verb composition.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/B0EhBw1PPwcpWE8Q0NAEhIwVLBWMw1@j/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>9</s> 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ð¶V
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8LZW&input=WzEyLCIxMiIsMTJdCjEy)

```
ð¶V     :Implicit input of array U and element V
ð       :Indices of elements in U
 ¶V     :That are equal to V
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 51 bytes

```rust
|a,v|(0..).zip(a).filter(move|a|a.1==v).map(|a|a.0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYzLCoMwEEX3/YrpRjIQhkRtC1b9jG5EJEgEwVc1ddHab7eJ3dYOXJg7wznjYzJr1UGr6o4hvA5gp9EGKkjWRfF5YYII6VkPTCFVdWP0yNp@1otaFMkkmZFaNbCtClwdf90sapr0aAp9P7KKeZn0OcjwG7sGgY1t7urnGVHOwZM@Utk3jS5NFMU3XcZFmjLkkAkOZw6XHH@67VduVus@OVG4K9oxhP5/TDjufVg/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

```
=ĐŁř*ž
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f9siEo41HZ2od3ff/f7ShjrGOmY5SRmpOTr5SLBeYBgA)

```
=           implicit inputs; is each element in the array equal to the value?
 Đ          duplicate resultant array
  Łř        get length and create array [1,2,3,...,<length>]
    *       multiply (does normal integer multiplication for integers, booleans,
            and floats, and does string multiplication for strings)
     ž      remove zeros; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript,48 bytes

```
b=>a=>a.reduce((a,e,i)=>(e===b&&a.push(i),a),[])
```

```js
let f=b=>a=>a.reduce((a,e,i)=>(e===b&&a.push(i),a),[]);

console.log(f(12)([12,14,14,2,"Hello World!",3,12,12]));         //[0,6,7]
console.log(f("Hello World")(["Hi", "Hi World!", 12,2,3,true])); //[]
console.log(f("a")(["A",true,false,"aa","a"]));                  //[4]
console.log(f(12)([12,"12",12]))                                 //[0,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

## D, 78 bytes

```d
int[]f(T)(T[]a,T e){int[]r;for(int i;i<a.length;i++)if(e==a[i])r~=i;return r;}
```

The calling mechanism is ... really odd: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xrsIwDEVn@ArD5KgREnNehw78QZmqDi5Ni6WQINeFAcGvl4DeG95g6ercc@V@WThq0w5YG6yblmwN3jy@TNyQBHMEdvxDu@DjqGfHRWF4QF@W1HBr5FWyE6@zRBD3XN8S93Ahjmge6xVfrkkUJu13@Ti5f@hGwhQ1QwpMExyhhCqMvhPi0wa7lILN/22f5i54O6lwHM1HnzVBle3mRJPi0eztb9getm0W7sLqQ8QBq79mb/LyuSxv).

D has a variant type!

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4, 46 bytes

```
{a,e in a.enumerated().flatMap{$1==e ?$0:nil}}
```

`a.enumerated()` produces an array of `(index, element)` pairs.

`flatMap` compares the element (the second member of the tuple, accessed by the implicit closure parameter `$1`), and either returns the index (the first member of the tuple, accessed by the implicit closure parameter `$0`), or `nil`.

`flatMap` has the effect of removing `nils` from the output sequence, so only the indices remain.

This is a byte shorter than the more obvious

```
{a,e in a.enumerated().filter{$1==e}.map{$0.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>77</s> 53 bytes

```
DEF S A,V
FOR I=0TO LEN(A)-1IF V==A[I]THEN?I
NEXT
END
```

Also works with strings/characters in addition to normal arrays/values.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 99 bytes

Not the best, but at least I try.

PD: Hate PHP's functions name

```php
function f($c,$a){return array_filter(array_keys($a), function($b)use($a,$c){return $a[$b]==$c;});}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtNCoMwEIX3PUUqAyYwG2131rrtDboQKTGOGJqaEM1Cime3kdLC48H7@dzgtkvlovdhVLO2I@s5KAQp3p7m4EcmvZfLo9dmJs@/4UnLxOMF2Y/i0IowUSwR1B8FWUPblCWoYhXFupEaLNMvZ2xHPMU08jzLkdXRsvOuHJMbGWPZ3XrTHRM84b7ljRDFobpuHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 66 bytes

```
{v:Any,l:List<Any>->l.mapIndexedNotNull{i,j->if(j==v)i else null}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwDIbvPkXcqYUqbHoabrCbgujBg@dCO@mM2ei6oow9e@0GGgJJ@MnH92wdGgr1QPCShpi0jz6Hylr5OdycNfQoOYwriOUlQm1IQRFGn1f0EZifTe8OcS03JW5fsjuR0m@tLq27DIijEc2mNDVrisJzAxp7DRSDaQo/IkYCFMu41izNRLqfOxPJUSO2cG8tqnUidmLOMv5X8fErzZazi54Oic12zIsFxvlqCl8)

[`mapIndexedNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-indexed-not-null.html) really is the powerhouse of this lambda. It's the same thing as `mapIndexed` (`map` with an additional index argument) with the added bonus that it excludes `null` results from the output. Find something we don't like? Return `null`!

```
{ v: Any, l: List<Any> ->          // lambda
    l.mapIndexedNotNull { i, j ->  // map with index, removing nulls
        if(j == v) i else null     // return index if equal else null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 2 bytes

```
ss
```

**S**tring **s**earch is in the `strings` library which is implicitly imported if your interpreter isn’t too old. It’s defined as `I.@E.` (compare with [the APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137374/74681)) so it can also look for sequences of values. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/oPBIZ6RgrFxQqGlnoGCiC2oZ65gpGCpZ6lpYKxnqGRgoWhkaWxnoWCoSGXho26W2ZVlbomSAOIleBUCiNAXFSeAhD4OekpFJcUZealcxkqGIDtAUMDIITQhkgsQwUUANZcmlScWliampecCgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 7 bytes

```
indices
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9BC8IwDIXv@xXP3hVXh4LCwJN68SLiQTyUroPiXGdbDzL222taUAaSEHjJ@0JSC@mNDefT4bhbQzhnpINTz5dqpXLorPL@3VndemyyPuuRc6SSFzE52F41jcHF2KaaMCzSjGOgmGBaknmOJVYYiB17GaLWLJYfTSCnFX6MJ1Ak@5bRqCZFMrZGriL5vsexnLO/K0hmA65Bt5Wm38KNVqWHy4fo4LyQ91n4AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 25 bytes

```
.[0]as$r|.[1]|indices($r)
```

All input to `jq` has to be valid JSON, so the examples need to be enclosed in brackets.  And boolean constants like `True` need to be translated to `true`, etc...  Other than that, it essentially sets things up to use a builtin function `indices()` which does exactly what the challenges wants.

```
.[0]as$r                  - Set var "$r" to what we want to find
        |.[1]             - Select the list of options...
             |indices($r) - Find positions of "$r" in the list
```

The output is a list of integers, with the offsets to matching entries.  The output is an empty list of the target isn't in the list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/18v2iA2sVilqEYv2jC2JjMvJTM5tVhDpUjz//9opUQlHYVoJUclnZKi0lSdtMSc4lQdpUSgKFAmNhYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
zI
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLqjwhDCh_wU19QyOuaEMjHQVDEwgGMpU8UnNy8hXC84tyUhSVdBSMgTIgFUaxCgoQfQA)

Built-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 75 bytes, `int` only

```go
func(e int,A[]int)(I[]int){for i,E:=range A{if e==E{I=append(I,i)}};return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc29CsIwEMDxPU8ROyVwiq0OYsnQoUNxcReHUJMStGkIqUvIk7gUwYfq25h-wMH_bvnd59t0w7gxvH7yRuCWK41UazrrdolsXYLQm1ss2a93cnsaL7LXNRFYaQfF7R5DSbXUy85iBeWZWa4jVXglsWCs9BXjxgj9IBUoGkJuheutDiuZT-T8mFDs0dVG7KWJJGkGeKZ93NLjNBns4QDTmQVK0UoMw9I_)

#### [Go](https://go.dev), 98 bytes, generic

```go
func f[T any](e T,A[]T,C func(T,T)bool)(I[]int){for i,E:=range A{if C(e,E){I=append(I,i)}};return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY6xasMwEIZ3P8WRSYJradwOpUVDCB68ZdBmPJxTKYjGkivkQhB6kiwm0Ifoo_RtatmBg7v7j_u__3o7uel3oOMnnRT0ZGxh-sH58LjRfdj8jEE_vP51erRH0I0EspeWKZC4a1qJe8gHJlHyzrkzZ3XTGht41M6DwepNeLKz7y4aDXumsOKxFjQMyn6wGg1P6d2rMHqb7qR-IeUcjEMsvmn2saH6ArGiCLssLLi4vgIJ0aXi4Gf9bJlm2xJhyRHnafuSq8QnfMa8lglXR86LO3Sa1v4P)

Golang is statically typed, so both solutions take in a homogenous slice.

The challenge as-written is possible with `interface{}` shenanigans.

#### [Go](https://go.dev), 133 bytes, as written

```go
func f[T any](e T,A[]any,C func(T,T)bool)(I[]int){for i,E:=range A{switch E:=any(E).(type){case T: if C(e,E){I=append(I,i)}}};return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZDPSsQwEMbxuk8x9pRAXNzqQVZ6WJbC7s1DwUPpIdtN1mCb1DRVltCjT-GlCD6Ej6JP47T1LyxCSCaTb37zTZ6ed6Z7rXh-y3cCSq70RJWVsW4ayNIFL42TJxdvj7LROcg0Aa73GRGQsEWaYcyW0D-RhCV0Y0xByTrNlHbUS2NBsXgeWa6RvPD1g3L5DWAG60hMp8TtK0F9zmvkzUFJWBLBYurXEa8qobdkzRRt2_bSCtdY3Y5m3o_I4Kb3Sij4yT3HTtrFdxCNZjjb9InBkB9rgUfRph2ktbN_pZhQendAfYV5V2giySxkMMzrMZqd9ytkp-yM9dewZWN_Sn9KUjyzw3XBShSFgWtji-1x8B-E_JYGX6hgpTDG_RsBSAgR5GwjkDNMiJzPD-u68fwA)

Uses [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73382479/8143168) to cast the generic type to `interface{}` so that it can be type-switched over.

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2 bytes

```
`?$_
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWSxLsVeIhTKjITYVopWhDIx1DExAy0jHQMdYBcY1ilXQUlAyNlGKhCgE)

Built-in.

```
`? Find indices
$   in the first argument
_   of the second argument
```